# On MacOS how can I manually specify the default compiler used by make install

Tags: macos, gcc, makefile

Basically amidst a certain make install I'm running some code gets compiled which works just fine with GCC but malfunctions with the native clang. So I'd like to sort of force make install to use gcc, any ideas?

Comment: What's a *"make install"*? Normally, AFAIK, a *"make"* is a build process during which programs get compiled and an *"install"* is a later stage of software creation where the compiled programs and their man-pages and configuration files get installed into the directories where they normally reside. If you wait for the *"install"* phase it is too late to be choosing a compiler, surely?

Comment: @MarkSetchell make install is a command which hence the name installs a directory with a makefile which has previously had make run on it. They’re pretty much exclusive to Unix so I added makefile as a tag in hopes that people would interpret them as those commands. :/

Comment: `make CC=/usr/local/bin/gcc` maybe?

Comment: @madprogramer sorry but your question is impossible to understand or make meaningful comments on, as stated.  Post exact code in minimal form, post what you expect, post what happened.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out by Mark Setchell, 
typing `CC=/usr/local/path/to/compiler` after the command should do it.